# Taking input as much as the given number in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying/looking for this problem and decided to ask.

I want a simple program that gets an integer as input first of all.

```
a = int(input())
```

Then, the program will take input as much as the given number, `a`.

Comment: Use a `for` loop: `[input() for _ in range(a)]`

Comment: I thought he meant the size of the input

Comment: I've never understood list comprehensions. Is there a way to do without it?

Comment: are you talking about taking a inputs or taking an input that is less than a

Comment: [An explanation of list comprehensions.](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)  You can define an empty list, then loop over the range using a for loop, appending `input()` every iteration of the loop.

Comment: @Primusa I am talking about taking a inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use a for loop to repeatedly get input from the user like so:

```
a = int(input("How many numbers do you want to enter? "))
numbers = list() #Store all the numbers (just in case you want to use them later)

for i in range(a):
  temp_num = int(input("Enter number " + str(i) + ": "))
  numbers.append(temp_num)
```

Comment: It looks like a painful way to do it, but the only way to do it without list comprehensions, I guess. Thanks.